# a macro which can copy data from word file and paste it into text area of a webpage

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to automate below process using macro:

- Browse word document from local machine
- Copy the data from that word document and paste into text area of below web page
  [Web page](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.mybluemix.net/?%20%20cm_mc_uid=&cm_mc_sid_50200000=&cm_mc_sid_52640000=)
- Click on 'Analyze' button from the web page
- Next click on 'keywords' button from the web page
  I'm not much familiar with vba.
  I have tried writing the code as shown in the image but I am getting

errors for this code.It will be grateful if somebody helps,Thanks 
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS5ca.jpg)

Comment: What code are you using? Please include it in your question.

Comment: VBA to create macro for excel

Comment: I dont think you understand the words you are using. What country do you live in? I need to understand your language first so that I can translate it.